# Colours of number of answers on answered questions illegible

Tags: bug, status-completed

There's been a change in the colours, for the worse:

> [image: Screenshot]

I couldn't tell you what colour the answer count used to be, but it used to be more contrasty and legible than this.

Comment: I'm guessing this is related to the occasion screw-y-ness experienced by all of the sites without the CSS update. It's been noticed on many of the sites in that category and there is a Meta.SE topic about it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267265/sff-and-mi-yodeya-and-other-sites-without-css-update-are-experiencing-odd-link).

Comment: @Catija you guessed it. We're pushing a fix. Once the site is converted and design is updated this should happen less often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about that. We accidentally added [a wrong file in another file](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267281/155160).